# construct a URL with pageReference params from LWC

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter, urlfor, callback

I am trying to construct a URL PageReference to a visualforce page passing in paramaters for Docusign use. This is working in Aura and also as a Custom URL button using a {!URLFOR} function, so I figure there is a way to do it in LWC. Our client wishes to make the full change to LWC going forward so they asked if we would be able to accomodate. Here is my code:

Apex Method:

```
@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static string getDocuSignUrl(String SourceID){

        Pagereference pg = Page.dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope;
        pg.getParameters().put('SourceID',SourceID);
        // pg.getParameters().put('DST',DST);
        return pg.getUrl();

    }
```

Here is what WORKS in Aura:

```
({

    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

        let action = component.get("c.getDocuSignUrl");

        action.setParams({

                        SourceID: component.get('v.recordId')

                    });
        action.setCallback(this,function(response){

            const returnValue = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log("docuSignPageUrl >>> ",returnValue);
            component.set("v.docuSignPageUrl",returnValue);

        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },

    goDocusign : function(component, event, helper){

        console.log('goDocusign!');
        const urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
        urlEvent.setParams({

            "url": component.get("v.docuSignPageUrl")

        });

        console.log('docusignUrl =' + component.get('v.docuSignPageUrl'));
        console.log('urlEvent =' + urlEvent);

        urlEvent.fire();

    }
})
```

It basically is Queueing up the URL with parameters I need (SourceID needs to be recordId) on init, then I can call it and launch the page with the second function, goDocusign. This is working as intended with the correct URL.

Here is my stab at it with LWC:

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent'
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import getDocusignUrl from '@salesforce/apex/QuoteWindowInfo.getDocuSignUrl';
import QDOC_NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.Name';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.SBQQ__Quote__r.Name';
import INTRO_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Introduction__c';
import PAYMENTTERMS_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__PaymentTerms__c';
import STARTDATE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__StartDate__c';
import TERM_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__SubscriptionTerm__c';
import QUOTE_ID from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.SBQQ__Quote__c';
import SPANNING_QUOTE_ID from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.SBQQ__Quote__r.Id';
import TEMPLATE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.SBQQ__Template__c';
import SIGNER_1_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.Signer_1_Name__c';
import SIGNER_1_EMAIL from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.Signer_1_Email__c';
import SIGNER_2_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.Signer_2_Name__c';
import SIGNER_2_EMAIL from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.Signer_2_Email__c';
import SIGNER_3_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.Signer_3_Name__c';
import SIGNER_3_EMAIL from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.Signer_3_Email__c';
import ACCOUNT_NAME from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__QuoteDocument__c.SBQQ__Quote__r.SBQQ__Account__r.Name';


const FIELDS = [
    NAME_FIELD,
    QDOC_NAME_FIELD,
    QUOTE_ID,
    SPANNING_QUOTE_ID,
    INTRO_FIELD,
    PAYMENTTERMS_FIELD,
    STARTDATE_FIELD,
    TERM_FIELD,
    SIGNER_1_NAME,
    SIGNER_1_EMAIL,
    SIGNER_2_NAME,
    SIGNER_2_EMAIL,
    SIGNER_3_NAME,
    SIGNER_3_EMAIL,
    ACCOUNT_NAME,
    TEMPLATE_FIELD
];


export default class QuoteWindow extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {

@api recordId;
@api error;
@api qid;
@api docusignUrl;
@api check1 = false;
@api check2 = false;
@api check3 = false;
@api showDocusign = false;
@api response;

// @track signer1Name;
// @track signer2Name;
// @track signer3Name;
// @track signer1Email;
// @track signer2Email;
// @track signer3Email;
// @track accountName;

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields: FIELDS })
wiredQuoteDoc({ data, error }){
    if(data){
        console.log('There is data!');
        console.log('record data: ', data);
        this.qid = data.fields.SBQQ__Quote__c.value;
        this.templateName = data.fields.SBQQ__Template__c.value;
        this.signer1Name = data.fields.Signer_1_Name__c.value;
        this.signer2Name = data.fields.Signer_2_Name__c.value;
        this.signer3Name = data.fields.Signer_3_Name__c.value;
        this.signer1Email = data.fields.Signer_1_Email__c.value;
        this.signer2Email = data.fields.Signer_2_Email__c.value;
        this.signer3Email = data.fields.Signer_3_Email__c.value;
        console.log('ACCOUNT_NAME value = ', data.fields.SBQQ__Quote__r.value.fields.SBQQ__Account__r.displayValue);
        this.accountName = data.fields.SBQQ__Quote__r.value.fields.SBQQ__Account__r.displayValue;
        error = undefined;
    }
    if(error){
        console.error('record errors are: ', error);
        data = undefined;
    }
};
constructor(){
    super();

    console.log('constructor() = doInit!');
    // const url = getDocusignUrl({ SourceID: this.recordId })
    // .then(result => { this.response = result })
    // .catch(error => { this.error = error })

    // console.log('result/response = ', this.response);
    // console.log('url = ', url);

}

// connectedCallback(){

//     console.log('docusignUrl connectedCallback: ', this.response);

// }
@wire(getDocusignUrl, { SourceId: '$recordId' })
getParams({ data, error }){

    if(data){

        this.docusignUrl = data;
        console.log('passed recordId = ', this.recordId);
        console.log('Docusign Url = ', this.docusignUrl);
        console.log('data:: ', data);

    }
    if(error){

        console.log('you have errors with Apex');

    }

}

handleCheck1() {

    if(this.check1){

        this.check1 = false;

    } else{

        this.check1 = true;

    }

    if(this.check1 && this.check2 && this.check3){

        this.showDocusign = true;

    } else{

        this.showDocusign = false;

    }

    console.log('this.check1 = ' , this.check1);
    console.log('this.check2 = ' , this.check2);
    console.log('this.check3 = ' , this.check3);
    console.log('this.showDocusign = ' , this.showDocusign);

}

handleCheck2() {

    if(this.check2){

        this.check2 = false;

    } else{

        this.check2 = true;

    }

    if(this.check1 && this.check2 && this.check3){

        this.showDocusign = true;

    } else{

        this.showDocusign = false;

    }

    console.log('this.check1 = ' , this.check1);
    console.log('this.check2 = ' , this.check2);
    console.log('this.check3 = ' , this.check3);
    console.log('this.showDocusign = ' , this.showDocusign);

}

handleCheck3() {

    if(this.check3){

        this.check3 = false;

    } else{

        this.check3 = true;

    }

    if(this.check1 && this.check2 && this.check3){

        this.showDocusign = true;

    } else{

        this.showDocusign = false;

    }

    console.log('this.check1 = ' , this.check1);
    console.log('this.check2 = ' , this.check2);
    console.log('this.check3 = ' , this.check3);
    console.log('this.showDocusign = ' , this.showDocusign);

}

goDocusign(){

    let urlParams = {};
    urlParams[SourceID] = this.recordId;

    this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl]({
        type: 'standard__webPage',
        attributes: {

            url : this.docusignUrl

        },
        state: urlParams
    }).then(generatedUrl => {

         console.log('final docusignUrl? ', this.docusignUrl);
         window.open(generatedUrl);

     });

}
```

the LWC returns a url, but WITHOUT the SourceID parameter I need. I have no idea why this is happening, I am trying the state: property as suggested around but it doesn't seem to want to do anything, can anybody help?

Aura URL = /apex/dsfs__docusign_createenvelope?SourceID=a0m3h000002Cq9YAAS&_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN=VmpFPSdsfs__docusign_createenvelope

LWC = URL = /apex/dsfs__docusign_createenvelope?_CONFIRMATIONTOKEN=VmpFPdsfs__docusign_createenvelope

Comment: did you try setting "urlParams['SourceID'] = this.recordId;" instead of  urlParams[SourceID] = this.recordId;

Comment: I modified it to urlParams['SourceID'] = this.recordId;, which now fires in the button and displays the console.log beneath it containing the url, but still does not include the SourceID parameter :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help everybody, but I was not able to find a way to get this to successfully generate the URL via LWC so I wound up going my Aura route. I have the LWC contained inside an Aura wrapper, the LWC passes events up to the wrapper, which then displays my 'Send with Docusign' button, then generates the URL based upon parameters obtained from the Quote Document record by passing it to an Apex Class which puts them on the end of the Visualforce Page url, then finally returning it with a getUrl(); method. This is the only way I was able to get it to work. Thanks again!